# Git ignore: How to match one or more digits

Tags: regex, git, gitignore

I would like to make sure that git ignores any log files that are created on a rotating basis. For instance

```
debug.log
debug.log.1
debug.log.2
debug.log.10
```

should all be ignored. I am currently using `*.log` and `*.log.[0-9]` to ignore the first 3 in the list. To capture the third, I know I could use `*.log.[0-9][0-9]`. However, I'd prefer to find a one line solution that could capture all of these.

Is there a way to tell the gitignore file to match one or more digits?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sadly but `.gitigore` use [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) instead of regex for matching, which means there's not a good way to do it.

> Otherwise, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag ...

Of course you can use:

```
*.log.[0-9]*
```

But notice this will also match something like `debug.log.9abc`. If you are okay with that, I think this pattern will be enough.

If you REALLY have to do it strictly, yes you have to list them all:

```
*.log
*.log.[0-9]
*.log.[0-9][0-9]
*.log.[0-9][0-9][0-9]
# ... And so on if needed.
```

Comment: The expression `*.log.[0-9]*` does not match `debug.log`.
How about the expression `*.log*` instead?